# get value from href into javascript

Tags: javascript, html, href

I wanted to get the values from the `href` link...

```
"uploads/kareena-kapoor-141a_$1$Wc.nm0.$t63sii3nBiDWA.jSueCAf.jpg?id=3&pic=98"
```

I want to get value of `id` in a variable and `pic` in another variable in javascript.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Do you have to get the URL from a DOM element like an `img` or `a` tag, or do you already have the string and just need help parsing

Comment: If that's the exact href, you can try this: http://jsfiddle.net/ttz6G/

Comment: A little more generic solution could be this: http://jsfiddle.net/ttz6G/1/

Comment: thanks a lot am not i am , this gave me the result i wanted , thanks a lot

Comment: @SakshiSharma: You're welcome. If the question gets reopened, I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: hey actally i was passing the value of pic id in a lightbox , but as i push the next button in lightbox the vale of pic id changes there but not from where i got the pic id . how to solve this any idea